# Home answering machine computer-based hw

Tags: phone

Is there a reasonable phone-answering h/w s/w set up that people can use on a land line?

I want to be able to use my land line like you use Skype, (completely computer controlled, and have the computer take messages as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Google Voice. It records messages, sends you a text (or email) transcription and allows you to screen your calls similar to how the old school phone answering machine once allowed.

[Here is a good article from the Google forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=049774e10816455a&hl=en) on how to use Google Voice like an answering machine.

Here is a video of how you can screen your calls. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eF-7UTvwAXs&feature=player_embedded#at=14

Comment: Ah, I see, and you can connect your land line to your computer using [a usb voice modem](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw=usb+voice+modem) (though I really wish I didn't throw out my ol' 14.4k Doom II modem!! Ah those were the days)